# nginx rewrite for wikkawiki

Tags: nginx, rewrite, wiki

Just setup WikkaWiki on my server, I have been trying to have the links go from `wiki.mysite.info/wikka.php?wakka=Start` into `wiki.mysite.info/DotMG`.

I tried following their guide at http://docs.wikkawiki.org/ModRewrite, however it seems incomplete and outdated. Furthermore, as of version `1.3.2` [`base_url`](http://docs.wikkawiki.org/ConfigurationOptions#hn_Discontinued) isn't even manually configurable from the `wikka.config.php` file.

I am using version `1.3.2` of WikkaWiki. My nginx virtual hosts file contains:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name wiki.mysite.info;

    root /usr/share/nginx/wikka/;

    access_log /usr/share/nginx/.access/wikka;
    error_log /usr/share/nginx/.error/wikka error;

    location / {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @wikka;
    }

    location @wikka {
            rewrite ^(.*/[^\./]*[^/])$ $1/ last;
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /wikka.php?wakka=$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thus far it works, I can go to `wiki.mysite.info/APage` and it'll display that page, however it doesn't work on all pages, sometime the browser simply downloads the page (For some reason it always downloads the `Start` page).

Also when I go to `wiki.mysite.info/` it downloads the `wikka.php` file...

Furthermore, the links on the wiki have the `wikka.php?wakka=` so whenever I navigate around the wiki, it goes back to being `wiki.mysite.info/wikka.php?wakka=APage`.

I think something is wrong with my `rewrite` but I can't say for sure.

Contents of the `fastcgi_params`:

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $server_https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

Comment: Post your `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`?

Comment: @quanta added to post :)

Comment: @Hans You have to set up Wikka to use clean URL's, I'm not sure how its done though (never used Wikka).

Comment: @jli That's true, however that is also the problem, it would seem that the WikkaWiki devs removed that feature (`base_url`), not sure why though. However that is only half the problem, the other one is actual the downloading `wikka.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
```

to:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks quanta, I changed the `fastcgi_params` file, however that seems to have done nothing. Whenever I go to `wiki.mysite.info/Start`, it just downloads the file instead of parsing and displaying it... :(

Comment: Did you restart nginx?

Comment: yes I did, `sudo service nginx restart`. No errors occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I came here through Google, and despite I had to find the solution myself, and even this thread is more than 1 year old, I think I have to post here my solution for other folks brought here by Search Engine.

I think that in nginx, the rewriting to location @wikka done by try_files is short-circuiting the call to the block `location ~ \.php`

Re-copying everything from inside the block `location ~ \.php` into `location @wikka` solved the issue for me. More on http://blog.dot.mg/?t=20

Comment: I never thought of that, alas I haven't been using nginx anymore due to issues like this. Apache is still far easier to setup and maintain then nginx. Thanks anyway for the answer, I am sure that others will find this very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished migrating an old Wikka installation to `1.3.5` and from Apache to Nginx/php-fpm.

For reference here's my vhost definition with the appropriate rewrite rules:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name wiki.domain.com;

    root        /var/www/wiki.domain.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/wiki.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/wiki.domain.com.error.log;

    location / {
        index       wikka.php;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ @wikka;
    }

    location @wikka {
        rewrite (.*)    /wikka.php?wakka=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files       $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```